Conflicting Bean Definition while Running Test Classes Spring Boot
I have a configuration class, let's call it TestConfig.
It is annotated with:
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class TestConfig implements ApplicationListener<EnvironmentChangeEvent>

While trying to run my application locally or running test classess annotated with @SpringBootTest (which load the whole application context), it throws conflicting bean exception:
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: 
Annotation-specified bean name 'testConfig ' for bean class [com.service.config.test.TestConfig] 
conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.service.config.test.TestConfig]

It looks like the bean is conflicting with itself because of the @RefreshScope annotation.
The test class I tried to run:
@SpringBootTest(
        properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
public class BigBangTest

I already ensured that there is no other bean with the same name and tried to add properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"} to my @SpringBootTest property, but the same exception still thrown.
I also tried to remove the @RefreshScope annotation from TestConfig and it works, no ConflictingBeanDefinitionException was thrown.
My question is, how to solve this while keeping the TestConfig annotated with @RefreshScope?

eh... so why not just remove it? you have not posted any motivation or user case as to why you specifically need the @RefreshScope annotation

@Toerktumlare Sorry for my late reply. The test config is actually configuration for Kafka Consumer. And I need to refresh its scope because on some cases, I need to turn the consumer off. And it can be done by busenv-ing its config and let it refresh (So I don't need to restart the instance to refresh the config).

read the docs, RefreshScope should not be defined on Configuration classes, it should be defined on specific Beans as it will lead to suprising behavior https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/spring-cloud-commons/application-context-services.html#refresh-scope also without the full picture its impossible for me to help you, as it says you are defining the bean twice, but you have supplied basically no code at all for us to look at.
